# How To set Footer at Bottom In Reactjs.... Irrespective of any Route component Length

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, responsive-design

i want to set my footer at bottom of screen in sticky mode not like position fiexd... and the footer should be at bottom of each component or each route... irrespective of their length
i tried like this... but when some component have length less than 100vh then footer are not in bottom

```
const BoxMain = styled(Box)({
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "black",
    position: "relative",
    bottom:0,
    // marginBottom:0
  });
  
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <BoxMain>
      <BoxWrapper>
        <Box>
          <Typography>
            Designed By: <br />
            <a
              href="https://chic-lollipop-cd173a.netlify.app/"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noreferrer"
            >
              Md Shamim Akhter
            </a>
          </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box>Right</Box>
      </BoxWrapper>`your text`
    </BoxMain>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

Comment: try using this position: sticky; top: 100%;